# Double-counting arguments interpretation

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to figure out situations that the following expression might be counting:

a) $n2^{n-1}$

b) $2^{n-d}\binom{n}{d}$

For (a), I thought about forming a committee from $n$ people by first choosing a president and then choosing a subset from the remaining $n-1$ people to complete the committee.

For (b), I thought about choosing a sub-committee of size $d$ and then from the remaining people $n-d$, choose a subset to complete the committee.

Do you think my scenarios are correct?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Thank you!

Comment: In other words, you count arbitrary size committees that have a board of  $d$ members (and (a) is the special case with $d=1$)

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

(a) looks right.

As does (b), as long as you clarify that the two committees are actually two distinct sets (the way your president from (a) is separate from the rest of the people in the committee).

Note that in any of the $2^x$ committees, the possibility of no people being chosen is there.